# Email рассылка, как сделать скошенные углы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка-email

[image: **введите сюда описание изображения**]

Как реализовать такие блоки в email рассылке? Ведь насколько я понимаю нельзя использовать псевдоэлементы и position:absolute.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле единственное кроссплатформенное решение - это вот прям пилить все эти куски скошенных углов картинками. 
Если макет в psd, например, берем направляющими размечаем все это на ячейки таблицы, так, чтобы были максимально широкие ячейки, которые можно просто залить цветом, например. В них и будет располагаться текст.
Дальше берем инструмент "раскройка" и по напрявляющим режем все это на фрагменты по нашим направляющим, сохраняем через экспорт для веб.
Размечаем такую же таблицу в документе, заполняем весе это соотвественно.
Если брать изображение автора, то выходит что у нас тут две ячейки с картинками. Низ слева от красного фона и низ справа от красного фона.

Конечно, можно взять и использовать картинки на бекграунде, но только в том случае, если мы не поддерживаем outlook.

Другого решения, чтобы все везде было хорошо, пока не знаю.

Answer (score -1):

У вас верстка табличная. В одной из td вы можете создать еще один table. И вот этому table задать бэкграунд со скошенным углом

Comment: это не является ответом

Comment: В любом же случае для этих двух блоков нужно использовать position:absolute? А его потом ни gmail ни outlook не прочтет. Как быть?

Comment: Добавьте сверху вложенной таблицы tr, в котором td с высотой, которая равна нужному отступу сверху

Comment: А как тут задать что угол скошенный?

Comment: Картинку сохранить в PNG. По другому, наверное, никак. CSS тут не помощник

Comment: Ок, допустим картинка будет наполовину срезанной уже, тоесть с белым участком внизу. Но как поднять красный блок, чтобы налезал на  эту самую картинку?

Comment: Вам этот блок надо будет поместить в table, у которого вы задали скошенный background. Регулировать отступ сверху можно с помощью строки tr, в котором надо будет поместить td с нужной высотой.